# on minimum vertices in a graph satisfying some properties

Tags: graph-theory

I was looking for minimal graphs (graphs with minimum number of vertices)  with following three conditions:

(1) Each vertex has degree at least $2$.

(2) Every cycle contains at least $4$ vertices.

(3) Graph has no automorphism except identity.

How can I proceed? This may be computational, but still in it, by some tricks, computations can be reduced. I don't have any clever idea for proceeding for this problem.

**My partial answer:** [This answer is wrong as pointed in comment by bof.] I thought following graph of six vertices is an example, but not sure about its minimality. Let $A$ be the square graph. Let $B$ be the square graph with one diagonal. Construct graph $G$ by gluing one side of $A$ with one side of $B$. Then $G$ has six vertices, and trivial automorphism. I was thinking, can there be example with five vertices?

Comment: Doesn't your example have a cycle of length three?

Comment: Oh, yes! thanks for noticing it; I had forgotten it to check.

Comment: I think you can get an $8$-vertex example by starting with an  $8$-cycle $v_0,v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5,v_6,v_7,v_0$ and adding two more edges, $v_0v_3$ and $v_1v_5.$ That's the smallest one I've been able to find. Maybe it is the smallest one, but I imagine verifying that could be quite tedious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way.

[Brendan McKay](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/graphs.html) provides data files with all simple graphs up to 10 vertices in graph6 format. A minimal example of your kind of graph must be connected, (otherwise a connected component would be a smaller example), so we can restrict our attention to the files with connected simple graphs on four or more vertices.

We can then feed these graphs to `countg` from the [nauty gtools](http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/):

```
./countg -d2: -g4: -a1
```

to select minimum degree at least two, girth at least 4, and trivial automorphism group.

There are no such graphs with 4, 5, 6, or 7 vertices. There are three examples with 8 vertices. The third is the one bof mentioned in comments.

[image]

[image]

[image]